# Why do I not get the same result when I run a TAIL command from console of a remote server as when I run the same command from a script on local svr?

Tags: linux, bash, remote-server, logfile, distinct-values

I connect to my remote server via ssh from the console

`[mylocalserver]$ ssh -p 27 myremoteserver`

On my remote server, I have a log file (mylogfile.log) that contains several lines

*File mylogfile.log contains 10 lines*

```
01 | Field 1 | Field 2
02 | Field 1 | Field 2
...
10 | Field 1 | Field 2
```

When I execute the tail command from the console of the server to which I am connected remotely, it returns the result as 5 different lines

`[myremoteserver]$ tail /usr/tmp/mylogfile.log`

*Return*

```
06 | Field 1 | Field 2
07 | Field 1 | Field 2
08 | Field 1 | Field 2
09 | Field 1 | Field 2
10 | Field 1 | Field 2
```

But when I run a script on my local server that includes the connection to the remote server and the tail command, I don't get the same result

*File on my local server `/usr/tmp/script.sh` contains*

```bash
#!/bin/bash

result=`ssh -p 27 myremoteserver "tail \"/usr/tmp/mylogfile.log\""`

echo ${result}
```

When I execute the script on my local server...

`[mylocalserver]$ /usr/tmp/script.sh`
*Return*

```
06 | Field 1 | Field 2 07 | Field 1 | Field 2 08 | Field 1 | Field 2 09 | Field 1 | Field 2 10 | Field 1 | Field 2
```

How can I solve this problem so that when I run the script on my local server, the result returned is each line of the file on the remote server and not a single line with all the original lines concatenated?

I was hoping to get the same result when execute script

Comment: `result="$(ssh -p 27 myremoteserver tail /usr/tmp/mylogfile.log)";echo "$result"` says what?

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting and then format your input, output, and code as Code Blocks. But first do what the [tag:bash] tag you used instructs: "For shell scripts with syntax or other errors, please check them at https://shellcheck.net before posting them here" so we don't waste time debugging issues the tool could've caught. And get rid of any ellipsis from your sample input/output, we need you to provide an example we can copy/paste to test with as-is.

Comment: Try to use ssh with -t flag that allows to execute command remotely.